# how to add 2 radio buttons in dialog box in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need call this on button's click event.

I want to perform further actions based on selected radio button.

```
$("#btnExport").click( )
```

Comment: Requirement unclear. Please elaborate with some code!

Comment: Its simple what I've already wrote. I need dialog/alert box containing two radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link. You need to use `.dialog` if yo want radiobuttons in dialog

http://jsfiddle.net/6FGqN/813/

Comment: Check new link http://jsfiddle.net/6FGqN/818/ if you want to retrieve value of checked radio button

Answer (score 0):

from what i understood.. i guess you need `trigger`

try this

```
 $('#yourbutton').click(function(){
     $('#radioID').val();//will give you the selected radio's value
     $("#btnExport").trigger('click');

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am showing you a simply alert on both buttons. Please change as ur need

```
<input type="radio" id="btnExport1">
    <input type="radio" id="btnExport2">

$("#btnExport1").click(function(){
    alert('First Button');
})
$("#btnExport2").click(function(){
    alert('Second Button');
})
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/kapil_dev/tq3Bm/

Comment: Well, thnx but I need radio buttons within alert box!

Comment: Pratik you can add a confirm box on select a radio button.

Comment: But I've got single button 'btnExport' on which inwant to display these two options.